# Click stacktrace in eclipse's external tools

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse's external tools functionality to launch my test server (I can't use the normal servers view for it since it's not supported).

That works fine, but it's a bit sad that I can't click the stacktraces to automatically jump to that line in the code (as you could normally do).  I always thought eclipse's console automatically recognized lines of code.

Is there any way to make it do that for external tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the stack trace to a Java Stack Trace console. In the Console, switch to a new Java Stack Trace console, paste the stack trace and it will be immediately clickable.

Also, check out the [LogViewer plugin](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/logviewer/), as far as I can recall, it can do that with less effort

Comment: I was hoping I could integrate that functionality in the standard console, which was the whole point.  So I suppose I can't.

Comment: Doesn't work here with both approaches. String like "at Function.unsubscribe (C:\git-repositories\winery\winery-modeller\node_modules\racer\lib\descriptor\query\QueryHub.js:109:18)" do not become clickable.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I created a simple Java wrapper program which executes the command given as arguments. This allows an Eclipse Java run configuration to be used instead of an external tool.

```
public class Exec {
    private final Process process;
    private boolean error;

    public Exec(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    public static void main(String[] command) throws Exception {
        new Exec(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)).run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> copy(process.getInputStream(), System.out));
        thread.start();
        copy(process.getErrorStream(), System.err);

        int status = process.waitFor();
        thread.join();
        System.err.flush();
        System.out.flush();
        System.exit(status != 0 ? status : error ? 1 : 0);
    }

    private void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```